# Reflection principles for linear second order elliptic pdes

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let $B_+\subset\mathbb R^n$ be the intersection of the unit ball with the upper halfspace and $u$ be a harmonic function in $B_+$ that vanishes identically in the flat part of the boundary of $B_+$.

We can easily see that $u$ can be extended to $B$ by $-u$ in $B_-$ in a harmonic fashion by using the mean value property (Schwarz reflection principle). This allows us, for example, to use interior estimates near this part of the boundary.

I wonder whether there are other similar ideas or techniques when $u$ solves weakly a PDE like
$$
\operatorname{div}(A(x)\nabla u(x))=0, \quad x\in B_+
$$
where $A$ is a symmetric, uniformly elliptic matrix with Lipschitz coefficients.
To be specific, assume that $A$ is only defined on $\overline B_+$ (so that we can redefine $A$ on $B_-$ anyway we want but keeping the global Lipschitz condition on the coefficients) and $u$ also vanishes identically in the flat part of the boundary.

**What I have tried:**
if the coefficients of $A$ have higher regularity I think that we can find a biLipschitz map $T$ from the upper half space to the lower half space and which is the identity on the hyperplane $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ such that
$$
\operatorname{div}(A_T\nabla (u \circ T)) = 0, \quad x \in T^{-1}(B_+)
$$
where
$$
A_T = \vert JT \vert DT^{-1} A \circ T (DT^{-1})^t
$$
and then we can join both domains $B_+$ and $T^{-1}(B_+)$ and both PDEs and solutions in a way that $A$ is still globally Lipschitz.

Comment: I should have been more clear with the question. I don't really care how weird is the reflection or the symmetry, I only mind whether I can extend $u$ (through the flat part of the boundary where $u$ vanishes) in a way such that it still is the weak solution of an elliptic PDE (uniformly elliptic, Lipschitz coefficients, ...)

Answer (score 1):

I think not. Set the dimension $n=2$ and consider the elliptic equation
$$u_{,11}+u_{,12}+u_{,22}=0$$
in $B_+$. The extension being $u(x)=-u(x_1,-x_2)$, it satifies in $B_-$ the equation
$$u_{,11}-u_{,12}+u_{,22}=0,$$
which means that the matrix is not even continuous accross the horizontal line.

Comment: But this PDE has constant coefficients, thus we could consider a linear transformation $T$ such that $u \circ T$ is harmonic in $T^{-1}(B_+)$. We could then reflect $u \circ T$ through $T^{-1}(\{0\}\times \mathbb R^{n-1})$ and finally undo this transformation (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @jgall. This transformation is not an isometry. Thus reflecting $u\circ T$ and then undoing the transformation yields a solution whose symmetry is uncommon.

Comment: I should have been more clear with the question. I don't really care how weird is the reflection or the symmetry, I only mind whether I can find an extension (through the flat part of the boundary where $u$ vanishes) that still is the weak solution of an elliptic PDE (uniformly elliptic, Lipschitz coefficients, ...)